# Always visible jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

How can I use jQuery UI to display an always-visible datepicker widget?

Comment: Someone maybe thinks that this is a stupid question, but this is useful for me. Thanks Piotr.

Answer (score 78):

It's simple. Keep your jQuery code, but assign it to a `<div>` instead of an input box.

```html
Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

A functional example lives at the [jQuery UI webpage for the datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline), and I've also included one below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: It's good to know also, that if you still want to store the selected date in some input field, there is "altField" option with target field selector as an argument: $("#datepicker").datepicker({altField: "#input_date"});

Answer (score 17):

From [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline):

> Simply call .datepicker() on a div
>   instead of an input.

(To display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay.)

Answer (score 4):

```
 .ui-datepicker {
z-index: 1000;
 width: 17em;
width:500px;
padding: .2em .2em 0;
display: none;
position: absolute;
padding: 100px 20px;
top: 100px;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
 }
```

i have overrided the style to the above one and now it works better