# Closing of dialog also closes datepicker - jsfiddle included

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple layout with a datepicker input field and a dialog. If I open the datepicker, and then close the dialog, the datepicker closes too. I would like to keep the datepicker 
open.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nwSgm/

Is this a bug or is it intentional behaviour?

Anyhow, does anyone know how to avoid this behaviour, so the datepicker does not close, when the dialog closes? Thanks!

Comment: It is an expected behaviour for datepicker! When you click outside of it, it hides.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188435/always-visible-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: The datepicker is visible again on clicking on the input field. Is there any reason you want datepicker visible even on clicking outside of it?

Comment: I have a dialog (with a help-text), that opens on clicking a help-icon next to the Today button. When the user then closes the help-dialog it would close the datepicker too, which is unfortunate in this case. I've solved it by using modal mode and CF Mitrah's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Praveen said, It is an expected behavior for datepicker! I did small work around for your need.

> http://jsfiddle.net/WzLc3/1/