# Embedded Persistant Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to figure out how to embed a persistent datepicker module into my web application UI. The goal is to get the date picker to show constantly rather than only appear in a tooltip, with the ultimate goal being that the data shown on the rest of the page will update automatically when a new date is selected.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have been scouring the internet for an hour now with no luck. There are plenty of examples on how to make the calendar appear by linking it to an action, or through an input, but none I have found that cause it to appear as permanent content on the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most datepicker I know, you can just start by javascript and there is no need to bind it to an element.

Comment: You can start it via javascript, sure. But if you want it to be a persistent object embedded in the html, wouldn't it need to appear in the HTML itself somewhere? That's my common sense feeling at least.

Comment: Sure, it is in the HTML, but it is inject by the datepicker. Just start the datepicker after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I feel silly. Just call datepicker() on a div via JQuery.
[Always visible jQuery UI DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188435/always-visible-jquery-ui-datepicker)
for reference.